# Many observer connected to one observable receive events one at a time

Tags: reactivex

This is how I create my observable:

```
Observable.fromCallable(new EventObtainer()).flatMap(Observable::from).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).repeat();
```

And after that, through http request i'm trying to add different observers. The thing is that if I have more than one observer I can't predict which observer will obtain emitted item. Why doesn't observable emit item to every subscribed observer, but one item at time to different observers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this,

In observable contract:
http://reactivex.io/documentation/contract.html
There is information:

> There is no general guarantee that two observers of the same
>   Observable will see the same sequence of items.

So i resolved it by making my observable Connectable observable by publish, and then invoke connect method on it:

```
Observable.fromCallable(new EventObtainer()).flatMap(Observable::from).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).repeat().publish();
observable.connect();
```

and now even if asynchronously i will add more observers it will emit obtained item to every observers.